# Angular reactive forms type mismatch on assigning the form values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to reactive forms,
I am trying to assign the form values (all string inputs) from my reactive form to a variable which has type of object of strings.
I get the following error

"Type 'Partial<{ taskName: string | null; taskDate: string | null; taskPriority: string | null; }>' is not assignable to type 'ToDoDetailType'.
Types of property 'taskName' are incompatible.
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

```
export class ToDoMakerComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(): void {
        
    }
    toDoForm = new FormGroup({
        taskName : new FormControl<string>('',[Validators.required]),
        taskDate : new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
        taskPriority : new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
    })
    toDoDetail:ToDoDetailType | undefined;
    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.toDoForm.value);
        this.toDoDetail =  this.toDoForm.value //error raising line
    }

}
```

```
export interface ToDoDetailType{
    taskName: string,
    taskDate: string,
    taskPriority: string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems here :

- `FormControl` creates a nullable control by default but you can't create a `nonNullable` with a validator. The common alternative is to use the `FormBuilder.nonNullable`.
- `todoForm.value` returns a `Partial<ToDoDetailType >` because any disabled `FormControl` won't be included in the value. If you're sure non control will be disabled the common alternative is `getRawValue()`.

Which gives us :

```
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}
  
  toDoForm = this.fb.nonNullable.group({ // create a non nullable group
    taskName: ['',  [Validators.required]],
    taskDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
    taskPriority: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  onSubmit() {
    this.toDoDetail = this.toDoForm.getRawValue(); // Not a partial
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do:

```
this.toDoDetail =  {
    taskName: this.toDoForm.value.taskName,
    taskDate: this.toDoForm.value.taskDate,
    taskPriority: this.toDoForm.value.taskPriority
}
```